# Model Structure for Zend Framework

Tags: database, zend-framework, join, model

I am new to Zend Framework and currently struggling with the implementation of Model. Actually, what I want is as follows:

I have two tables (am using MySQL):
**Musicians(id, name)**
**Albums(id, musician_id, album_name)**

Now, I want to design the model, so that I can create an efficient join query in there.

I have tried many things, but am unclear about various things. For example, currently I have created a Table class (which extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`), a model class and a `model_mapper` class. I am not sure, what code to put in which file and how actually I am going to call the model functions (containing the query result) in the action function in controller.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to this question.  The best code to put in each class is based on the application logic your requirements call for.

There are methodologies to guide object-oriented design:

- [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29)
- [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)
- [Domain-Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/)

  - This free e-book has an introduction to DDD: [Domain-Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly)

Comment: Hello Bill, thanks for your comments. By the way, I just found out and was able to execute the join query as follows:             $select = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from($this->_name, array('custom_title' => 'title'))        
                ->join('musicians', 'albums.artist_id = musicians.id',
                    array('musician_name'=> 'name'));
        
        $rows = $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
        return $rows;